# Android Java Creating Multiple Databases

Tags: java, android

EDIT3: I decided to put them into separate documents as this is how i had them when they did work this morning. When i checked the database only user was being shown but they all have pretty much identical code except the constant values are changed.

UPDATED LOGCAT:

```
04-29 02:25:52.236: W/KeyCharacterMap(11342): No keyboard for id 0
04-29 02:25:52.236: W/KeyCharacterMap(11342): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-29 02:26:03.816: D/dalvikvm(11342): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1931 objects / 121640 bytes in 76ms
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.gofitness.www/databases/gofit.db, table = users, query = SELECT userid, username, password FROM users
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at com.gofitness.www.logindetails.getData(logindetails.java:88)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at com.gofitness.www.view.onCreate(view.java:17)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-29 02:26:03.826: E/Cursor(11342):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:03.926: D/dalvikvm(11342): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 765 objects / 66120 bytes in 61ms
04-29 02:26:09.915: I/Database(11342): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Achievements
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342): Error inserting Achievement=tyrenzo
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Achievements: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Achievements(Achievement) VALUES(?);
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at com.gofitness.www.AddAchievements.createEntry(AddAchievements.java:80)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at com.gofitness.www.Achievements$1.onClick(Achievements.java:41)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-29 02:26:09.925: E/Database(11342):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:11.776: W/KeyCharacterMap(11342): No keyboard for id 0
04-29 02:26:11.776: W/KeyCharacterMap(11342): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-29 02:26:14.805: I/Database(11342): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Achievements
04-29 02:26:14.805: D/AndroidRuntime(11342): Shutting down VM
04-29 02:26:14.805: W/dalvikvm(11342): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gofitness.www/com.gofitness.www.AchievementView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Achievements: , while compiling: SELECT AchievementID, Achievement FROM Achievements
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Achievements: , while compiling: SELECT AchievementID, Achievement FROM Achievements
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at com.gofitness.www.AddAchievements.getData(AddAchievements.java:88)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at com.gofitness.www.AchievementView.onCreate(AchievementView.java:17)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-29 02:26:14.845: E/AndroidRuntime(11342):    ... 11 more
```

This is AddAchievement.java

```
 package com.gofitness.www;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AddAchievements {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "AchievementID";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "Achievement";


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gofit.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Achievements";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {





        public DbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(
                    "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + 
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                    );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
                    onCreate(db);
                    }

    }
    public AddAchievements(Context c)
    {
        ourContext = c; 
    }

    public AddAchievements open(){
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;


    }
    public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();  
    }

    public long createEntry(String check, String checkpass) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME,check);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iUser = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);


        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iUser) +"\n";
        }
        c.close();
        return result;
    }

    public String getName(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                DATABASE_TABLE +
                " where username = "+ "'"+ s+"'" , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            c.moveToFirst();

                 int iUsername = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
                    String Name = c.getString(iUsername);

                   c.close();
                    return Name;

            }
        return null;
    }


}
```

This is AddAchievementDB.java

```
package com.gofitness.www;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AddUserAchievementsDB {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "AchievementID";
    public static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id";
    public static final String KEY_COMPLETED = "Completed";


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gofit.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "UserAchievementsDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {





        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dbachievements) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dbachievements.execSQL(
                    "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + 
            KEY_ROWID + " INT NOT NULL,"+ 
            KEY_USERID + " INT NOT NULL," +
            KEY_COMPLETED + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                    );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dbachievements, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (oldVersion==2){


                    dbachievements.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
                    onCreate(dbachievements);
                    }}

    }
    public AddUserAchievementsDB(Context c)
    {
        ourContext = c; 
    }

    public AddUserAchievementsDB open(){
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;


    }
    public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();  
    }

    public long createEntry(String check, String checkpass, String completedDB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ROWID,check);
        cv.put(KEY_USERID,checkpass);
        cv.put(KEY_COMPLETED,completedDB);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERID, KEY_COMPLETED};
         String sql = "SELECT * FROM UserAchievementsDB INNER JOIN Achievements ON UserAchievementsDB.AchievementID=Achievements.AchievementID WHERE UserAchievementsDB."+KEY_USERID+" = " + Constants.UserID + ";";

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iUser = c.getColumnIndex("username");
        int iCompleted = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPLETED);


        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iUser) + c.getString(iCompleted) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getName(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                DATABASE_TABLE +
                " where username = "+ "'"+ s+"'" , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            c.moveToFirst();

                 int iUsername = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERID);
                    String Name = c.getString(iUsername);


                    return Name;

            }
        return null;
    }


}
```

AddStats.Java

```
package com.gofitness.www;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class AddStats {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "userid";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "height";
    public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
    public static final String KEY_CALORIES = "calories";
    public static final String KEY_PROTEIN = "protein";
    public static final String KEY_CARBS = "carbs";
    public static final String KEY_FATS = "fats";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gofit.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "stats";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {





        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dbstats) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dbstats.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + 
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_AGE + " INT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_CALORIES + " INT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_WEIGHT + " INT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_HEIGHT + " INT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_PROTEIN + " INT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FATS + " INT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_CARBS + " INT NOT NULL);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dbstats, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (oldVersion==1){

            dbstats.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(dbstats);
            }

        }

    }
    public AddStats(Context c)
    {
        ourContext = c; 
    }

    public AddStats open(){
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;


    }
    public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();  
    }

    public long createEntry(String usernamevar, String agevar,String weightvar,String heightvar,String caloriesvar,
            String proteinvar, String carbsvar, String fatvar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME,usernamevar);
        cv.put(KEY_AGE,agevar);
        cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT,weightvar);
        cv.put(KEY_HEIGHT,heightvar);
        cv.put(KEY_CALORIES,caloriesvar);
        cv.put(KEY_PROTEIN,proteinvar);
        cv.put(KEY_CARBS,carbsvar);
        cv.put(KEY_FATS,fatvar);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE,KEY_WEIGHT,KEY_HEIGHT, KEY_CALORIES,KEY_PROTEIN,KEY_CARBS,KEY_FATS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iUser = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iAge = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
        int iWeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEIGHT);
        int iHeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HEIGHT);
        int iCalories = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CALORIES);
        int iProtein = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROTEIN);
        int iCarb = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARBS);
        int iFat = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FATS);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iUser) + "\n Age: " + c.getString(iAge) +"\n Weight: "+ c.getString(iWeight)+"\n Height: "
                + c.getString(iHeight) +"\n Calories: "+ c.getString(iCalories)+"\n Protein: " +c.getString(iProtein)+"\n Carb: " + c.getString(iCarb)+ "\n Fat: "+ c.getString(iFat) +"\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE,KEY_WEIGHT,KEY_HEIGHT, KEY_CALORIES,KEY_PROTEIN,KEY_CARBS,KEY_FATS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                DATABASE_TABLE +
                " where username = "+ "'"+ Constants.SESSION_NAME+"'" , null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iUser = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iAge = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
        int iWeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEIGHT);
        int iHeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HEIGHT);
        int iCalories = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CALORIES);
        int iProtein = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROTEIN);
        int iCarb = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARBS);
        int iFat = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FATS);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            int in = Integer.valueOf(c.getString(iCalories));
            int calories = in + 300;
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iUser) + "\n Age: " + c.getString(iAge) +"\n Weight: "+ c.getString(iWeight)+"\n Height: "
                + c.getString(iHeight) +"\n Calories: "+ calories+"\n Protein: " +c.getString(iProtein)+"\n Carb: " + c.getString(iCarb)+ "\n Fat: "+ c.getString(iFat) +"\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

AddStatsForm.java

```
package com.gofitness.www;

import android.app.Activity;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AddStatsForm extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText username, age, weight,height, calories, protein, carbs, fat;
    TextView success;
    Button submit;



     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle viewInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(viewInfo);
        setContentView(R.layout.stats);

         submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEnter);
          username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
         age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
         weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
         height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
       calories = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCalories);
         protein = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProtein);
         carbs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCarbs);
          fat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFat);
          success = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSuccess);





   submit.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

     @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         boolean diditwork = true;
            try {

                String usernamevar = username.getText().toString();
                String agevar = age.getText().toString();
                String weightvar = weight.getText().toString();
                String heightvar = height.getText().toString();
                String caloriesvar = calories.getText().toString();
                String proteinvar = protein.getText().toString();
                String carbsvar = carbs.getText().toString();
                String fatvar = fat.getText().toString();

                AddStats entry = new AddStats(AddStatsForm.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(usernamevar ,agevar, weightvar, heightvar, caloriesvar, proteinvar, carbsvar, fatvar);
                entry.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                diditwork=false;
                }finally{
            if(diditwork){
            success.setText("WERKED");  
            }
                }
     }}
```

Comment: Specifically what do you mean that your tables other than `users` do not work?  I don't see any methods in your `MyDb` class that try to retrieve data from any table other than `users`.

Comment: The methods exist in different classes. However the methods do not work because the tables do not exist. user tables exist however none of the other tables exist which is causing a crash on my app.

Comment: Can we see the other classes trying to access the other tables?

Comment: Sure, but bear in mind that these classes have accessed the table once before, it's since i erased the data from the simulator i cannot create any tables. I will put them up with the edit.

Comment: I think You meant multiple tables not databases?

Comment: What do You mean by "erasing the user data"? What did You do?

Comment: You are correct multiple tables my bad.
In Eclipse the simulator has a "wipe user data" option, i used that.

Comment: I've had no luck with the "wipe user data" option. Delete the app from the emulator and reinstall.

Comment: What do you mean delete the app from the emulator? Am i being really stupid, because i usually just run the app on the emulator within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for trolling in but I think I see the root problem.

AFAICT, onCreate in SQLiteOpenHelper is called ONLY ONCE for only ONE of your DBHelper classes when the database version number is CHANGED or the db does not exist; it will not be called for each of your separate classes, merely for the first one to be called. Thereby creating the first table but not the others.

One (not recommended & unsure if it'd work) fix would be to house each table in separate databases,  and then use *dbname.tablename* in your sql to access them.

---

From your code, I am a little unsure of the overall design patterns that you wish to employ, so the rest of this may be a bit off-topic:

If you want to create tables "as required", it may be better if you put in SQL to check if the table exists & create it if not. (inefficient but reliable)

```
/** does table exist? **/
private boolean txists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '" + tableName + "'", null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Otherwise from all that I've read, the pattern for DBHelpers of all sorts appears to be a singleton

```
private static MYDBHelper dbhelper = null;
public MYDBHelper getDBHelper(){
    if( dbhelper == null ){
        dbhelper = newInstance(...);
        ...
    }
    return dbhelper;
}
```

---

If you are trying to achieve a "pluggable" architecture, encapsulating table specification and creation in each of your classes; think interfaces and hooks utilised from a single DBHelper class rather than one dbhelper in each of your plugin classes (AddAchievements & AddStats).

Finally, you may want to think about a ContentProvider as a means of accessing your data (yes, I know it looks like an unnecessary layer of abstraction and complication, but it makes sense when you scale up and expand the functionality of your app, especially when talking to other services, adding searches, notifications, etc; it also provides a single centralised place to site your DBHelper, table creations, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I may be blind but can't find this "wipe user data" in my emulator to check how it works.

Check in DDMS File Explorer directory /data/data/your.app.name/databases
delete all files from there and run app again.

Your tables have names with all letter lower case but in cases when You get errors you use first letter capitalized.
Create constants for table names like You did with columns and use them instead to avoid confusion

//edit

The code Your provided now is completely different from previous and this one just can't work.
DBHelper is one and common for all tables but You made it separate for each of them.
As result of that You have just one table users because this is one You access as first.

If You wish to keep all tables in separate classes You have to make an DbHelper class separate as well not as inner class for each of them.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm fairly new to this, i have heard about the DDMS File Explorer but have no idea how to use it, could you possibly explain?

Comment: Also the "Wipe user data" is upon launch from the android virtual device manager, it's a tickable option in the same block as sizing of the emulator. Thanks all i appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks, just deleted all the databases. Re-run the apps and the exact same error Occurred. I tried my Achievement option and it crashed saying Achievement table not found.

Comment: Could You post LogCat output, there may be some more useful informations than just error

Comment: Done in the edit, thanks for this. This is pretty urgent for me and this sudden collapse of my project has really got to me.

Comment: Could You post all code just for one case. LogCat output is for activity selecting from stats table but code You posted is inserting into Achievements table. Plus could You post full logcat after You delete databases to see if there is something during onCreate. Try increasing DB_VERSION maybe.

Comment: Re-edited pal, this is me trying to insert into the database and then view the results from the database after deleting the database.

Comment: Done that and still no change :(
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users) (which my code is now) would this cause any problems?
Basically on some parts i get the no table found but once the table is found i get NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION too :(.

Comment: Are You using everywhere constants and still gets no table found error? Did You delete database after changing code?

Comment: Yeah, and i have just checked the database and the only table that has been created is "users". This is so frustrating, again i appreciate the help man you're a god!

Comment: Hmm i had similar code to this before and it worked, very strange! Would it be possible (and probably bad coding) to create all my tables where i create the user table? What do you suggest is the best way forward, to put them all in the same file like before or to make different DbHelper classes so they're separate? 

Thanks a million!

Comment: just on DbHelper class for all of them. Check out [This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)